# WebRTC echo cancellation when clients are in the same physical room

Tags: webrtc

We are trying to use WebRTC with two clients that are in the same physical room, where one of the clients have the microphone disabled. 
We are however, facing issues with echo cancellation, as the sound from the secondary clients speakers, can be heard through the first clients microphone, causing an endless loop.

We tried setting up the same scenario with Discord, who are supposedly using WebRTC, and it worked fantastically, so we are wondering what the best way of achieving the same results are.

Hoping for some help on where to go from here!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the two clients are not making a calling between them as one mic is muted. Therefore, they are probably in some conference call. It sounds like the issue you have is that you need to configure your AEC to support the long echo tail you have in the system. Check out this post on [how to analyze the echo tail](https://solicall.com/analyze-the-echo-path-yourself/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems like you are correct - our delay is too long for WebRTC to handle it. Do you know any way to configure it easily, or would we have to implement a different AEC that can handle it?

Comment: Sorry I don't. Many AEC engines have fix limits since they are unable to efficiently handle long tails.